# How to do Exception handling for Azure PartialBatchErrorException in python while deleting blobs from a container

Tags: python, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

How to print which blob it was trying to delete and failing due to partial error?
Using Azure library, (azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient) im trying to delete blobs if present from a list of names.

Sometimes, there are cases where the list of names provided as input does not have a blob with that name. during these cases, we get "PartialBatchErrorException " . According to their documentation it has 3 options : PartialBatchErrorException(message, response, parts)

Doc : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-blob/azure.storage.blob.partialbatcherrorexception?view=azure-python

But using this if im passing say 1000s of files say in a list, i want to which succeeded and which failed and frankly i m not seeing anyway to get this out. This seems to be a fairly simple ask, but not sure if the exceptionClass is not printing this or if im missing something.

Question 2 : would love to see if someone has a parallel way to deleting blobs .

```
rom azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient,PartialBatchErrorException
conn_str_for_list = "connection-string"
blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(conn_str_for_list)
container="blob-container-name"

container_client = blob_service_client.get_container_client(container)

file_name = "blobs.txt"
fileobj = open(file_name, "r")
entityIdsList = [line.rstrip() for line in fileobj]
fileobj.close()

blobs_list = entityIdsList

print(blobs_list)

try:
    result = container_client.delete_blobs(*blobs_list)
    for item in result:
        print(item.status_code)
except PartialBatchErrorException as e:
    print(e.message)
    print("-----------------------")
    print(e.response)
    print("-----------------------")
    print(e.parts)
    print("-----------------------")
    for part in e.parts:
        if (part.status_code == 202):
            print("Blob delete request was accepted.")
        elif (part.status_code == 404):
            print("Blob does not exist. Consider it deleted.")
        else:
            print("Something else happened. You better take a look at it.")
            print(part)
        print("==============================")
```

This part thing has only status_code, im not able to see for which blob he's getting 404 for example.

Answer (score 1):

Part answer to your problem.

> But using this if im passing say 1000s of files say in a list, i want
> to which succeeded and which failed and frankly i m not seeing anyway
> to get this out. This seems to be a fairly simple ask, but not sure if
> the exceptionClass is not printing this or if im missing something.

Considering `part` is essentially an object of type `HttpClientTransportResponse`, you can access it's `request` property and then `url` property of that `request` property to get the actual blob URL.

For example, you can use `print("Blob: " + part.request.url)` and it will print the URL of the blob in `/container-name/blob-name` format.

Here's the revised code:

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient,PartialBatchErrorException
conn_str_for_list = "connection-string"
blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(conn_str_for_list)
container="blob-container-name"

container_client = blob_service_client.get_container_client(container)

file_name = "blobs.txt"
fileobj = open(file_name, "r")
entityIdsList = [line.rstrip() for line in fileobj]
fileobj.close()

blobs_list = entityIdsList

print(blobs_list)

try:
    result = container_client.delete_blobs(*blobs_list)
    for item in result:
        print(item.status_code)
except PartialBatchErrorException as e:
    print(e.message)
    print("-----------------------")
    print(e.response)
    print("-----------------------")
    print(e.parts)
    print("-----------------------")
    for part in e.parts:
        print("Blob: " + part.request.url)
        if (part.status_code == 202):
            print("Blob delete request was accepted.")
        elif (part.status_code == 404):
            print("Blob does not exist. Consider it deleted.")
        else:
            print("Something else happened. You better take a look at it.")
            print(part)
        print("==============================")
```

Comment: Thanks again Bro, Does, the BlobServiceClient run deletion in parallel?

Comment: AFAIK, no. The client will send a single request that can contain up to 256 blobs.